# jquery toggle breaks float in ie

Tags: jquery, css

I have some text in a div I want to display on the right side of an image.  I want the text to wrap around the image and align with the left side of the page after it reaches the end of the image.  The visiblity of the  div is toggled using a little jquery script.  The problem is that when the visibility is toggled, the text no longer expands to the left margin of the page after it reaches the bottom of the image - rather it continues on as if the image were the left margin.  the html basically looks like this:

```
<html>
   <image float:left>
   <div id="toggleMe">lots of text here</div>
</html>
```

Note these two things:  This problem does not happen in firefox, only IE (untested with other browsers).    Also,  If the visiblity of the image is not toggled it works fine in IE.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(loadStuff);

function loadStuff() {
    $("#divWorkExperience").hide();


    $("#btnShowWorkExp").click(function () {
        $("#divWorkExperience").toggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
```

snip

```
<div style="text-align:justify;">

   <img src="ContentImages/highres_22409206.jpg" style="height:300px;width:400px;float:left;clear:none; margin-right:6px;" alt="me" />
   <div id="divWorkExperience" style="display:block; clear:none;">lots of text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wanna set up a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Try adding this style to your image

position:absolute;

Answer (score 0):

As usual I have to post the question before I can find the answer.  I dont understand why this works but it it does:

```
function loadStuff() {
    $("#divWorkExperience").hide();


    $("#btnShowWorkExp").click(function () {
        if ($.browser.msie) {
            $("#divWorkExperience").toggle();
        } else {
            $("#divWorkExperience").toggle("slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: it's working because there is no animation, strictly hide/show which toggles `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need.
Put align:left as an image attribute.
Use a span instead of div

```
<body>
    <img align="left" src="" style="height:300px; width:400px; margin-right:6px;" alt="me" />
    <span>Your long text here</span>
</body>
```